# Do aircraft engineers take into consideration engine placement to avoid ground strikes in a cross-wind landing?

Tags: aircraft-design, safety, accidents, multi-engine

On a multi-engine airplane with wing-mounted engines, do aircraft designers have a standard way of ensuring that the banked landings associated with cross-wind's do not cause a prop or engine-housing strike on the ground if the pilot were to over-bank?

Is there some rule such as, "*the wing tip would need to be the first part to strike if the wheel is in contact with the ground*", or similar standard of practice in design?

Comment: There are videos out there of jets dragging engines on the runway.

Comment: This is not opinion based.  There either is a rule or there is not a rule.  You not knowing does not make it someone else's opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For jet aircraft, there is no rule about preventing a nacelle from contacting the ground before the wingtip. There will be a design requirement that the airplane can touch down at a certain angle of bank and have the landing gear touch down but not strike a nacelle or wing, but not whether nacelle or wing must strike first. The nacelle is already designed for a wheels-up landing, so it's possible it could survive better than a [wing tip.](http://avherald.com/h?article=44cb78fa/0000&opt=0) While it's certainly more of a risk on [4-engine aircraft,](http://avherald.com/h?article=49707f00&opt=0) it can also happen on [twin jets.](http://avherald.com/h?article=43bb0ef8&opt=0)

Propeller aircraft are typically designed such that gear and wingtip will make contact without the propeller making contact, either through having gear directly below props on a low-wing configuration, or through a high-wing configuration. While a jet engine nacelle can sustain some structural damage in a strike, it will typically not affect the engine's operation. If a propeller gets damaged it could cause that engine to become unusable, making it much more difficult for the crew to successfully perform a go-around.